# Weird iCloud transaction log error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, icloud

Yet another day, yet another iCloud error, I'm trying to get to some sort of stability. at least for a little functionality. Please explain to me what this error is about.

Here's when it occurred: Two devices sharing the same app (obviously). Both work quite well when both are online.

But, I took my iPhone without a sim and a network out for a day, added a bunch of stuff to it. And all changes are reflected within the app (obviously) and came back home, iPhone went online automatically via wifi. I didn't touch the iPhone nor did I open the app.

I fired up the iPad and launched the installed app. I expected the changes to just magically appear after taking some time of course, instead only a single update happened. That too was related to adding  a  new "User" entity. Not the stuff in it, or other new entities in it or related.

Here's the log part which I think is responsible, please tell me what's that all about, how did fetchedProperties come in? And how isToMany in there?

```
[NSFetchedPropertyDescription isToMany]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x43ad70
2012-02-24 23:06:01.216 App[3922:3877]
CoreData: Ubiquity: Error importing transaction log: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x4a198c0>
transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x5685140>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/PRSWRAABE7~com~testcloud~app/hgdata/mobile.D188D9B6-3C35-5E55-BB09-9BD78EC0CA64/com.testcloud.app/Zi4JIL_IINn2U12TdLepz0QoF922tqFvbcUPpcr3blU=/D320175C-FFA1-4C5C-A8C9-7CD23E85CAFD.1.cdt
transactionNumber: 39, 
exception: -[NSFetchedPropertyDescription isToMany]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x43ad70
2012-02-24 23:06:01.216 App[3922:3877] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter operation:failedWithError:](839): 
CoreData: Ubiquity:  Import operation ecountered an error: 
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" 
 UserInfo=0x63359a0 {exception=-[NSFetchedPropertyDescription isToMany]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x43ad70} 
 while trying to import the log file at the URL: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x4a198c0>
 transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x5685140>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/PRSWRAABE7~com~testcloud~app/hgdata/mobile.D188D9B6-3C35-5E55-BB09-9BD78EC0CA64/com.testcloud.app/Zi4JIL_IINn2U12TdLepz0QoF922tqFvbcUPpcr3blU=/D320175C-FFA1-4C5C-A8C9-7CD23E85CAFD.1.cdt
transactionNumber: 39
```

Answer (score 0):

unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x43ad70 this message says that something going wrong with your code.

what is [NSFetchedPropertyDescription isToMany] ?? maybe it says that there are too many import transactions? looks weird

Comment: my guess is as good as yours. Its not even like NSFetchedPropertyDescription was specifically used..    isToMany sounds like something to do with a tomany relationship thing, but its a transaction log error, and nothing is certain.. People at apple dev forums advised to file a bug report.